# How to create and set a ActiveX Control CommandButton as a variable Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am trying to Create a New ActiveX Control CommandButton with Excel VBA. I have a loop VBA which has worked in the past, theFile1.1.xlsm has the master list of the workbooks. I need to add a CommandButton to ~3200 workbooks, so I will be using the Do-Loop macro. Here is the Loop code for reference.

```
Sub Macro2() 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Const scWkbSourceName As String = "theFILE 1.1.xlsm"

Set wkbSource = Workbooks(scWkbSourceName)
Set wksSource = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Replace 'Sheet1' w/ sheet name of SourceSheet

Const wsOriginalBook As String = "theFILE 1.1.xlsm"
Const sPath As String = "E:\ExampleFolder\"

SourceRow = 5

Do While Cells(SourceRow, "D").Value <> ""

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    FileName1 = wksSource.Range("A" & SourceRow).Value
    FileName2 = wksSource.Range("K" & SourceRow).Value

    sFile = sPath & FileName1 & "\" & FileName2 & ".xlsm"

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

        ''insert code for loop operation

    '''CLOSE WORKBOOK W/O BEFORE SAVE
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.EnableEvents = True

SourceRow = SourceRow + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

I would like to have the button set as a Variable (i think), so I can edit the formatting/properties and hopefully add a macro to the button later.

```
    Dim buttonControl As MSForms.CommandButton

    Set buttonControl = _
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
        Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
        Left:=1464, Top:=310, Width:=107.25, Height:=30)

    With buttonControl.Opject
        .Caption = "OPEN FOLDER"
        .Name = "cmd_OPEN_FOLDER"

    End With
```

I have a 'Run-time error 13: Type Mismatch' error. I am unsure why, because a 'CommandButton1' is created in the correct place.

Comment: `buttonControl.Opject` - Opject? That looks like a typo to me - but I don't think you even need `Object` in there either.

Comment: @dwirony I'm at a loss. What are you recommending?

Comment: Is that not a typo of `Object`?

Comment: Oh! You're correct but that doesn't seam to be the problem. the problem seams to be on or just after this line

    Set buttonControl = _
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
        Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
        Left:=1464, Top:=310, Width:=107.25, Height:=30)

Comment: What line is highlighted when the error occurs? And like I said, my guess is that you don't need `.Object` in there - just `With buttonControl`. `.Caption` is a property of `CommandButton`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OLEObjects.Add` creates an `OLEObject` and adds it to the `OLEObjects` collection; the object returned by the `Add` function is `OLEObject`, not `MSForm.CommandButton`. That's the underlying type of `OLEObject.Object` - so, set your `buttonControl` to the `.Object` property of the returned object:

```
Set buttonControl = _
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", _
    Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
    Left:=1464, Top:=310, Width:=107.25, Height:=30).Object
```

The button is created in the correct place, because the `Add` function works and returns - what's failing with a type mismatch is the assignment of the returned `OLEObject` into a `CommandButton` variable, immediately after that operation.

The subsequent `With` block can then be just `With buttonControl`.

Comment: Ahh. So then would his next line still just be `With buttonControl`?

Comment: Ah I almost had it!